# asp.net LoginView keeps redirecting to default.aspx, how to change?

Tags: asp.net

I have a LoginView control on my homepage, when i click 'Login' it goes to the log in page. When the details are authenticated, it redirects to default.aspx, I don't have a default.aspx - where can I change this?

This is the only thing I can see wrong:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet);
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the   defaultUrl specifies where to go after.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want this on your login control.
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet); 
because this would be coming in from a a login page rather then control.

I think you want change the control from being a login, to more of a "Logged In" control. IE: hide the username and password and display a label which states "Logged in as xxx/Logout Link.